# I have an early version of my database but still cannot attach it to my visual studio project or my local server

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, visual-studio-2019

I've set up a SQL Server 2017 database with SSMS 18.1 and I've set a Winforms project in my VS 2019 and every thing works great, but when I'm adding the `.mdf` file to my project, it doesn't work.

I've tried to connect to `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` from SSMS and tried to attach the database file, but I still get the same error.

As you can see I have the early version of the database but it still throws an error.

[database version error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQyb0.png)

[image]

Comment: If you're going to post an error, please post it as `text` or in a blockquote, not as an image. Some of that error is not in English as well, meaning that it is impossible for those of who don't speak your language to translate it.

Comment: The error is clear: the database file you've created is from SQL Server **2017** (version 869), but the server on your machine only supports SQL Server **2016** or earlier. You ***CANNOT*** attach/restore a database from a more recent version to an older server - just cannot be done. You need to update your local server to at least **2017** to support this `.mdf` File